# BOOTSTRAP GRID: Links unclickable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter, grid, blogger

I am using bootstrap grid design for my blogger layout. However, when the screen becomes xs size, all links in the post becomes unclickable.

It seems like some overlay issue. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTMl element in the aside element inside column-right inner is covering the  html element containing the posts.

Here is the css path of the element that is covering your posts:

```
.column-right-inner > aside
```

An easy fix would be to use the bootstrap helper class "hidden-xs" which will hide this aside only on smaller screens.

```
<aside class="hidden-xs">
```

Additionally, I think you have syntax errors: column-right-outer, col-xs-12, col-md-4 should be without the commas:

```
<div class="columns-inner, col-xs-12">
<div class="column-center-outer, col-xs-12, col-md-8" style="float: left;">
<div class="column-center-inner">
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried, however, if it is set to hidden, my whole sidebar info would disappear. I wanted it to be at the end of the page. Any other suggestions on what else I can do?

Comment: I think you can fix the issue by removing the commas in your class attributes.